# Starting and stopping child processes from main process only when needed in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, process.start, kill-process, child-process

I'm somehow new to nodejs and child processes and coming into some trouble now within my application. Something about the background: I have a nodejs-Websocket-Server working that loads a HTML page to any user thats is connecting. If the user is pressing a button on the HTML it sends a message to the server, that it should start an image capturing process (as a child process in node). So you can compare that to some kind of an infinite loop that runs in the child. So far so good, that works for me.

But now, if the user presses the button again, the child process should be stopped, so the image capture wont go any further. My problem is, that i have no idea how to stop the child process from the main process without killing it completly (the user should be able to start the loop again).

This is a snippet from the main process ("start" is either true or false, depending on if the user has pressed the start-button. Everytime the user clicks the button "start" changes its state):

```
var aCapLive = child.fork(__dirname + "/cp_capture_liveimg_async.js");  //Livebild
if (start) aCapLive.send(start);
else aCapLive.send(start);
```

And this is from the child:

```
var i = 0;
process.on("message", function(message)
{
    while(message)
    {
        console.log("CP aCapLive received message: Iteration " + i++);
    }
    console.log("CP aCapLive is going to exit now...");
    process.exit();
}
```

Obviously this doesnt work for me, because I'm running in my loop and cant detect any changes in "message". I would be very thankful if anyone had some ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as you have it, will never receive more than one message because it immediately goes into an infinite loop which never returns control to the event loop. The `message` variable is never going to magically change, and, since node is single-threaded, there is no possible way for the child to exit unless the very first message evaluated to false.

I think you're wanting something more like this:

```
var i = 0;
process.on("message", function(message)
{
    if(message)
    {
        console.log("CP aCapLive received message: Iteration " + i++);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("CP aCapLive is going to exit now...");
        process.exit();
    }
});
```

If you want an infinite loop, you have to return control to the event loop after every iteration. This will allow a chance for new messages to come in. Example:

```
var _message;
var _running = false;
process.on("message", function (message)
{
    _message = message; // update the _message var when a new one comes in
    if (!_running) // this just prevents multiple loops from being started.
    {
        _running = true;
        run();
    }
});

var i = 0;
function run ()
{
    if(_message)
    {
        console.log("CP aCapLive received message: Iteration " + i++);
        setImmediate(run); // <-- this causes an infinite non-blocking loop
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("CP aCapLive is going to exit now...");
        process.exit();
    }
}
```

If `message` is going to be the same every time, what you actually want is a toggle system as such:

```
var _message = false;
process.on("message", function ()
{
    _message = !_message; // update the _message var when a new one comes in
    if (_message)
        run();
});

var i = 0;
function run ()
{
    if(_message)
    {
        i++;
        if (i % 10000 === 0)
            console.log("CP aCapLive received message: Iteration " + i);
        setImmediate(run); // <-- this causes an infinite non-blocking loop
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("CP aCapLive is going to exit now...");
        process.exit();
    }
}
```

Here's the parent process code I used to test it:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');

var proc = childProcess.fork('child.js');
proc.send(true);
setTimeout(function () { proc.send(true); }, 4000); // send second message
```

Output:

```
CP aCapLive received message: Iteration 10000
CP aCapLive received message: Iteration 20000
CP aCapLive received message: Iteration 30000

... full output omitted for brevity ...

CP aCapLive received message: Iteration 1660000
CP aCapLive received message: Iteration 1670000
CP aCapLive received message: Iteration 1680000
CP aCapLive is going to exit now...
```

Comment: Well, yes i had it like this before, but the problem is that i WANT to execute an infinite loop when "message" is true. When the user clicks the button again, message should change to false and the loop should stop. Maybe i have the wrong idea to do sth. like that, but thats atm the only way i can imagine it ;)

Comment: Okay, there's a way to do that, but it's more complicated... here, I'll write it out.

Comment: Now i get the following error in the console: (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next
 version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Sorry, then simply replace `process.nextTick()` with `setImmediate()`. SetImmediate still allows I/O to pass through, so it should work.

Comment: Hm, i did this and my loop runs and runs and runs but never gets stopped by pressing the button again. :(

Comment: I verified that the code I posted works. Perhaps your problem is that when you "press the button again" the `message` that is sent evaluates to true, and therefore doesn't break the loop. If that's the case you either need to make sure that when you press it again `message == false`, or you need to setup a toggle system, and I added an example for that.

Comment: Hi Bret, thx for your help! But i dont know whats going wrong here...I tried out your toggle system (and I like the idea behind) but that doesnt work for me neither :( With your last example, when I press the button again it doesnt break the loop but start another one. Dont know whats going wrong...seems like I cant break the loop for some reason. I just copied the example from you to avoid any typos but i cant get it to work..

Comment: I added the full code I used to test it, and the output. It will definitely work as long as the second message is sent properly. If you're worried about whether the second message is ever received, put a console.log in the `process.on("message"` callback. Also make sure you don't have an infinite blocking loop somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Ahh, idiot me! Sorry Bret for having so much trouble with me. I had a simple mistake in my main process and just realised that now. I have had forked the child process everytime i was clicking on the button. I fixed it and now I'm only forking the child process at the top of my main process. Now even your second code example works fine for me. The loop goes about 1-2 iterations further after pressing the button to stop it, but then it stops properly. I thank you very very much, you helped me a lot. Wish you a good day! :)

Answer (score 0):

I made some bugfixing, so now I can start and stop the loop as often as I wish (replacing process.exit() with clearImmediate(id) so the process can be executed again and again):

```
var _message;
var _running = false;
var i = 0;

process.on("message", function (start)
{
    _message = start; // update the _message var when a new one comes in
    if (!_running) // this just prevents multiple loops from being started.
    {
        _running = true;
        run();
    }
});


function run ()
{
    if(_message)
    {
        console.log("CP aCapLive received message: Iteration " + i++);
        var id = setImmediate(run); // <-- this causes an infinite non-blocking loop
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("CP aCapLive is going to exit now...");
        _running = false;
        clearImmediate(id);
    }
}
```